# How to create a unique index with certain conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Giving he following table (invoice_detail):

```
invoice_id| job_id
------------------
1         |  1
2         |  2
3         |  3 
3         |  3
```

I want to add a rule/constraint, so that each job_id in the table must have always the same invoice_id. But an invoice_id can have different job_ids, or there can be multiple records with the same (invoice_id, job_id).

In other words: I can make an invoice that includes several jobs, or an invoice that includes the same job more than once. But a given job in this table must always have the same invoice_id.

Is there any way I can create such constraint in Mysql? I'm using MariaDB 10.1

Comment: Will you allow several records will the same `(invoice_id, job_id)`?

Comment: yes, there can be multiple records with the same (invoice_id, job_id)

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

You would do this by having the `invoice_id` column the in *`jobs`* table.

You would then look up the unique `invoice_id` for each `job`.

This information is not appropriate in this table.  It does not correctly model the relationship.

Comment: The jobs table also has a invoice_id foreign key pointng to the invoice table. I can do the check for duplicates via code, but I was wondering if it was possible to add a restriction via a unique index somehow, to prevent this bug from happening again.

Comment: Yes: remove the `job_id` column from the `invoice_detail` table. If those two columns are the only columns in `invoice_detail`, then just drop the table. It's redundant, and susceptible to bugs, as you have discovered. If you want to know the jobs that belong to an invoice, then query the `jobs` table.